# MS SQL: использование DELETE TOP c ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
DELETE TOP (@count) 
FROM [dbo].[Goods]
WHERE [Timestamp] < DATEADD(DAY, @daysOld, GETDATE())
```

Я не понимаю как использовать в данном случае **ORDER BY** т.к. в любых вариациях, когда я пытаюсь его использовать получаю ошибку типа **Incorrect syntax near 'ORDER'**

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу использовать ORDER в данном примере**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий SQL. Используя обновляемое выражение Common Table Expression (CTE).

Вам нужно будет указать конкретный столбец или столбцы для columnList.

**SQL**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP(@count) *
    FROM [dbo].[Goods]
    WHERE [Timestamp] < DATEADD(DAY, @daysOld, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY columnList
)
DELETE FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал, у Вас гораздо приятнее вариант, чем тот что я сам придумал